# Rails: Production Authlogic Problem with find_using_perishable_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

So I'm pretty puzzled by this one. This works in development mode and had worked in production mode before, but I just got this hoptoad error that said this:

An error has just occurred. View full details at:

http://goldhat.hoptoadapp.com/errors/2418099

Error Message:

NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_perishable_token!' for #

Where:

password_resets#create

[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb, line 260

Now my password resets and user email verification doesn't work because this method (and the reset_perishable_token! method) is apparently undefined. I can't conceive of where to begin with this problem).

Answer (score 1):

Might make sure you have the perishable_token in your database, if you don't I don't think authlogic defines the method.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue "NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_perishable_token!'" and it take me 8 hours to figure out. I hope this can help someone in the future.

1) Make sure you have "perishable_token" column
2) Make sure you get the correct user record and call "reset_perishable_token" method

My problem is i get the wrong user record to call the "reset_perishable_token" method.

Before: user = User.where(["users.email = ?", email])
After : user = User.where(["users.email = ?", email]).first